# Getting the index of an attribute in parser in antlr4

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I have a grammar which looks like

```
statement
     :  ME second_part
     {
           System.out.println($ME.getStartIndex());
           System.out.println($second_part.getStartIndex());
     }
     ;

ME   : 'me'
     ;
SPACES : [ \t\n\r] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

I want to get the start indices of Me and second_part.

I am getting an error when I run the above antlr4 grammar

> System.out.println($second_part.getStartIndex());
>
> missing attribute access on rule reference second_part in $second_part

How can I get starting index of second_part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every parser rule is a `ParserRuleContext`, which has a `start` and `stop` token. So, try this instead:

```
System.out.println($second_part.start.getStartIndex());
```